# Adding external api to EdX

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, edx, openedx

I am currently creating a custom javascript problem which will sit in the Edx platform

http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-partner-course-staff/en/latest/exercises_tools/custom_javascript.html

I have created my Javascript in react.js and currently works outside of the EdX platform, but when I add it to EdX, it doesn't call the Google maps API. I am including it in EdX's raw HTML using the following link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-KEY"></script>
```

I don't have any http referrers on the api key, so nothing is being blocked from using it.

No errors appear in the console. And despite an in-depth search, I can't find EdX documentation to tell me how to include the api.

Has anyone found a way to include, specifically Google maps, but any external APIs in to EdX?

Comment: Examine the HTML in the browser for clues about what happened to the script tag.  Also, the edX mailing list might be a better place to get answers: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/edx-code

Comment: Also we are working on a Google Maps XBlock (https://github.com/ExtensionEngine/xblock-google-maps). Check it out, you might find helpful code there.